# Running a python script over multiple files to extract messages

Tags: python, email, ole, extract

I have found a handy python script online that allows me to extract the text and attatchments from a .msg file (saved email from outlook)

-link to the script: https://github.com/mattgwwalker/msg-extractor

If I run the script fron cmd I need to write the filename that is being used:

*Python msgextractor.py filename.msg*

I need to extract the attatchments of many files from a single folder.
So I somehow need python to loop over all the .msg files in the folder and run the script. (preferrably from a second .py file)

I would be thankful for all the help and tips!

Answer (score 0):

Try glob. It allows you to easily iterate over files.

```
import glob
files = glob.glob('folder/*.msg')
for file in files:
    # whatever you do to individual files goes here
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I used/modified in his script at the bottom

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    writeRaw = False
    toJson = False
    useFileName = False
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk('D:\\Sync\\Images\\'):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(".msg"):
                print file
                savePath =  os.path.join(root) 
                for filename in glob.glob(file):
                    msg = Message(filename,savePath)
                    print 'boom'
                    msg.save(savePath, toJson, useFileName)
```